# Testing Net::HTTP.get_Response()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a method I have on one of my rails models. I am returning the HTTP status from a url and don't know how I can stub the return to test out different return codes to make sure my code works for different situations.

Here's the line of code I want to mock:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(self.url))
```

I want to have the `Net:HTTP.get_response` to return a specific HTTPResponse for each of the tests I have in my spec.

```
describe Site do
  before :each do
    FactoryGirl.build :site
  end
  context "checking site status" do
    it "should be true when 200" do
      c = FactoryGirl.build :site, url:"http://www.example.com/value.html"
      #something to mock the Net::HTTP.get_response to return and instance of Net::HTTPOK
      c.ping.should == true
    end      
    it "should be false when 404" do
      c = FactoryGirl.build :site, url:"http://www.example.com/value.html"
      #something to mock the Net::HTTP.get_response to return and instance of Net::HTTPNotFound
      c.ping.should == false       
    end
  end
end
```

How would I stub out the return values from get_response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [fakeweb](http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/) for this, e.g.:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get,
  "http://example.com/value.html",
  :body => "Success!")

FakeWeb.register_uri(:get,
  "http://example.com/value.html",
  :body => "Not found!",
  :status => ["404", "Not Found"])
```